# Missing styles on images when sending email with html embedded

Tags: c#, css, .net, email, email-attachments

I have to embeded an image in an email

```
<img src="....." style="float:right;height;400px;"/>
```

I create and alternate view this way

```
try{
  System.Net.Mime.ContentType mimeType = new     System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);                            
 AlternateView avHTMLImage =  AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(msgMail.Mensaje, mimeType);                               
LinkedResource lrHTMLImage;
 System.IO.MemoryStream img = new  System.IO.MemoryStream(Imagen.Image2Bytes(ie.img));
 lrHTMLImage = new LinkedResource(img, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
 lrHTMLImage.ContentId = ie.nombreImg;
 avHTMLImage.LinkedResources.Add(lrHTMLImage);
 avHTMLImage.ContentId = ie.nombreImg;
 this.mail.AlternateViews.Add(avHTMLImage);
}
```

But it is attaching and embedding the image without the settings of float neither height I'm telling it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try and avoid using css where possible in an email. you may find that it's something to do with perhaps the loading order of the css? Some basics to adhere to just in case http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/ways-to-build/css-in-html-email. Put the styling in, the old way eg...

```
<img src="....." align="right" width="..%" />
```

and then set the width, making sure that the image is proportionally correct to the width. Setting heights in an email is tricky as clients like outlook and online email viewed in IE will ignore and use the default image size.

FYI also use

```
display:inline-block
```

on your images to avoide unwanted margins in gmail